# Не удаётся собрать проект Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Ошибка сборки:

> {route}.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Из описания ошибки следует, что зависимости были скомпилированы с разной версией языка Kotlin. Но я не пойму, как можно это поправить. Подскажите, пожалуйста

````
```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1"

    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'

    implementation "com.github.skydoves:powerspinner:1.2.7"
}

    namespace 'com.example.project'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```
````

Comment: А Котлин-то как у вас в проекте настроен?

Comment: Нужно у себя в проекте повысить или настроить (если не задано) версию котлина не ниже чем у используемой библиотеки (1.8.0)

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja
В gradle проекта так:
'buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0''
Выше поднимать боюсь, потому что массово тянутся другие ошибки

Comment: Тогда версии зависимостей понижайте.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, означает ли это, что проект со временем начнёт отмирать из-за невозможности обновлять библиотеки, что делает разработку неудобной ?

Comment: Собственно говоря, я и пришёл к ошибкам сборки, пытаясь подтянуть более свежую версию одной из библиотек

Comment: 1.5 это уже древний Котлин, либо оставайтесь на старых версиях зависимостей, либо тяните все вверх.